# Objective-C: detect if an object has no more holders

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory, memory-management

I use an NSMutableArray as a "Window Manager" to store all my NSView objects, I send it like

```
[windowManager addObject:self];
```

right after ViewDidLoad of each NSView;

the question is, how can I detect on my "windowManager" NSMutableArray if it stores objects that has been called to release (and windowManager is the only one holding their instance)?

After I call a release upon an one of these NSViews and turn

```
SomeNSViewPointer = nil;
```

, I also need the WindowManager to check the above.

Comment: Are you worried about memory leaks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this:

```
[someNSViewPointer release];
SomeNSViewPointer = nil;
```

Do this instead:

```
[someNSViewPointer release];
[windowManager removeObject: someNSViewPointer];
SomeNSViewPointer = nil;
```

I would have to question why you are storing two references to your view though.  I think your design needs reviewing.

Comment: this could work, but then, what about if i have a LocationManager Helper class that contains an NSMutableArray where it stores all its delegates for location updates?

Comment: @Alon: In that case, you have to send a message to the LocationManager helper class to remove the view from its list.  However, you might also want to consider how *Key Value Observation* might help you. i.e. your views could observe the location property of your helper class and update themselves when the property changes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try if([myView retainCount] == 1), then it is only retained in the windowManager.

[EDIT] Read about retainCount in NSObject reference. As JeremyP suggests, it is not smart to use this in your code, but think better of your code design.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/retainCount

Comment: bbum (an Apple engineer) says: if you are calling retainCount, you are doing it wrong. http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/

Comment: @Amir was asking how to know if the windowManager is the only one holding the instance of the view, and that is how you could do it... I never called retainCount in my code.

Comment: @KakoSquid: you can't use retainCount to determine if you need to remove an object from an array.  What if some internal part of the runtime has also retained the object?

Comment: what if you have some kind of a sharedInstance, say, a LocationHelper that contains multiple delegates that all of them get location updates once there is a location update. all of these delegates wont ever be released if you dont remove them from the locationHelper's delegates array.

Comment: This is a terrible idea, since there may be objects in flight that recently retained your view, and which have either not yet released it, or called `autorelease`, in which case your view will be showing a different, and possibly indeterminate `retainCount`, from the one you expect.

Comment: @Jonathan, have you read my whole answer? I was suggesting that this was a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

When you add anything to your NSMutableArray via 'addObject', that NSMutableArray does a retain on it. You will need to remove that object from the NSMutableArray to have it released, if that is what you are after.

```
[yourNSMutableArray removeObjectIdenticalTo:yourNSView];
```

Comment: offcourse I need to, thats why im asking when and how i should know when to remove it from there : }

Comment: So, Why don't you know when to release it then? If you are responsible for releasing the object, you are the one that knows when to release it. At that time, remove it from the Array. What's the confusion?

Comment: If you don't know whether or not the object you want to release is in the array or not, check. If it is there, then remove it. See edit to this answer for example.

Comment: this could work, but then, what about if i have a LocationManager Helper class that contains an NSMutableArray where it stores all its delegates for location updates?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Is this NSMutableArray you are talking about in this context (within LocationManager helper class) the same NSMutableArray you referred to initially? I'm not clear on what you are asking now?

Answer (score 0):

You can send the view you are checking the `-(int)retainCount` message and check if it is one (ie the single retain from adding it to the array)? This question raises a red flag that you are doing soemthing that might be considered bad design, why are you doing this?

Comment: Since this answer is now accepted, I'll reiterate: **Seriously, this is a really bad idea.  DO NOT USE IT**

Comment: He points this out in his answer. The key for good answers is to answer, not to lecture about style, methods, sense or religions. People still need to learn from their mistakes themselfs.

Comment: @Helge: There's nothing religious about avoiding using the `-retainCount` method.  It simply doesn't do what you want.  Don't use it.  This is a bad answer because it might encourage people to do the wrong thing. As it stands the answer does not point out that using `-retainCount` is bad, only that the question is symptomatic of a (possibly) bad design.  That's why I have down voted.

Comment: @toiletseat: If you reword the first sentence, I'll remove my down vote.

Comment: @JeremyP I'm leaving my answer as it is, because it answers his question, and he *might* have a good reason to do it. I just hope he reads the second part, and gives us an answer!

Comment: @toiletseat: No, there is no good reason to use retainCount ever.

Comment: @JeremyP Yes, there are good reasons to use retainCount, debugging and profiling being two examples. I'd agree there are *very* few good uses for it in release code, but Alon might be in one of these camps.

Comment: @toiletseat: No, debugging and profiling are not good reaons to use retainCount. In any case, the question is not about debugging or profiling.

Comment: (comments were flagged for review; I see no inappropriate comments here etc, but let's draw a line, eh?)